# Why doesn't my Google chart work on Safari?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, safari, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a chart on screen using Google charts. It works on every browser except for Safari. The following is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the bar chart package.
    google.charts.load("current", {"packages":["corechart", "line"]});
    
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    
    function drawChart() {
      $.ajax({
            url: "/get-data-for-chart",
            data: {"objectId": 807},
            dataType: "json"
        }).then(function(response) {
            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
            rawData = response;
            if (rawData.rows != null) rawData.rows = rawData.rows.map(row => ({ c: [{ v: new Date(row.c[0].v) }, row.c[1]] }));
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(rawData);
    
            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: "Title of the chart"
                },
                width: 900,
                height: 500,
                hAxis: {
                    title: "Time Axis",
                    format: "MM-dd",
                    gridlines: {count: 15}
                },
                vAxis: {
                    gridlines: {color: "none"},
                    minValue: 0,
                    format: "currency"
                }
            };
    
            var date_formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
                pattern: "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"
            });
            date_formatter.format(data, 0);
    
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        });
    }
</script>

<!--Div that will hold the chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

What actually happens on Safari is that the area for the chart loads, but with incorrect labels I guess. And the actual chart does not load at all. Moreover, there are no errors shown in the console, so I can't debug this in a usual way. As mentioned earlier, this works with all other browsers. Also for the record, the Safari is running on MacOS Mojave. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: not sure, but every issue I've had with safari and google charts has been caused by dates. will you please share a sample of the data?